# react rendering and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

While I understand the use of state and rendering a component, I'm having trouble with this particular situation.

I have a set of questions and I want to pick a random number from 0 to the question length (in my case 8) without the numbers repeating.

I have figured that logic out but when I assign the random numbers to the state it seems that the re-rendering is causing this logic to reset each time and thus the numbers repeat. i need to THEN link to the question id with the corresponding random number.  or something of this nature.

```
const SomeComponent = props => {
  const [random, setRandom] = useState(null)

  function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    let stepOne = max - min + 1;
    let stepTwo = Math.random() * stepOne;
    let result = Math.floor(stepTwo) + min;

    return result
  }

  // this creates the array[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  function createArrayOfNumbers(start, end) {
    let myArray = [];

    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      myArray.push(i)
    }

    return myArray
  }

  let numbers = []

  function generator() {
    let numbersArray = createArrayOfNumbers(0, qAndA.length - 1)
    let finalNumbers = [];

    while (numbersArray.length > 0) {
      let randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0, qAndA.length - 1)
      let randomNumber = numbersArray[randomIndex];
      numbersArray.splice(randomIndex, 1);
      finalNumbers.push(randomNumber)
    }
    for (let nums of finalNumbers) {
      if (typeof nums === 'number') {
        numbers.push(nums)
        // for some reason i was getting undefined for a few so i weeded them out here and pushed into a new array
      }
    }
    const tester = numbers.splice(0, 1) ** this part works fine and
    console.log(tester) // each time my button is pressed it console logs a non repeating random number until ALL numbers(from 0 to 7 are chosen)
    setRandom(tester) // THIS IS THE LINE THAT SCREWS IT UP.re rendering seems to toss all the previous logic out...
  }


  return (<button onClick={generator}>click this to call function</button>)
}
```

Everything up to the last line works.

It's giving me a random number and the button I have which executes the function (thus giving the random number)

DOES NOT repeat the random numbers and gives me something like 0 then 4 then 1 etc. each time I click it until it gives me all the possible numbers from 0 to 7.

But when I include the last line which sets the state to those random numbers each click it seems the re-rendering of the page resets this entire function, thus forgetting to NOT repeat and forgetting all the previous logic.

To clarify something: this needs to be done with state because I want to set a random question to this random number state, then render a random question without it repeating (think of a basic quiz).

I also do not want the amount of numbers set or determined. It needs to work dynamically considering I will be adding more questions over time to the quiz.

Comment: Look, you are missing one important point, that you are really losing everything when you rerender. you can store your "used numbers" array into the memo hook, or you can also store your array to a state hook. P.s. I would recommend you to try Angular also, so you will have an option to compare the frameworks.

Comment: Unrelated, but posting JS code that isn't actually JS code (use JS comments) and a lack of whitespace in both the code and text makes things *harder* to reason about, not easier.

Comment: yeah its actually kind of ridiculous how u lose everything when you re-render... react is kind of silly in that regard. also passing props UP to another component is such a nightmare. react sort of forces you to structure code in such a specific way that it becomes such a headache and causes sooo many rewrites. but anyways thank i will look into that memo hook. im very new to react so lets see if that helps! thanks

Comment: @DaveNewton im really new to stack overflow so sorry about that. would love if you could look through it though i tried to add some comments...

Comment: I think you're over-complicating this (and have unrelated functionality in the component). If the only point is to take a list of questions and grab a new, random question with each click, just have an array of questions, shuffle it, and on each click pop the question off the previously-shuffled list.

Comment: I agree with @DaveNewton (he beat me to it) It makes more sense to simply shuffle your `qAndA ` array ***once*** when the component mounts and simply iterate through it to consume it.

Comment: @RobertO'Toole You don't "lose everything when you re-render" unless that's what the code implements. You don't need to pass props *up* the hierarchy; props are passed *down* the hierarchy.

Comment: yes guys i totally agree. shuffling the array would do the exact same thing. i got caught up and overcomplicated it. i am also realizing i dont really need to set the state to this number at all... the use of state might not even be necessary either! i was thinking i would need this to be in a state in order to link with something like <Link to='/qestions/${id}'>    but now i am realizing i can do that logic without using state (hopefully) will keep you all posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this demo I threw together: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-pine-0hxxi?file=/src/index.tsx

I understand I'm not answering your question about your current code directly, but I think your high-level issue is that you're approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Your approach looks like this:

```
component => create data => render
```

When often the best way to do it looks like this:

```
receive data => component => render
```

I think your problem is actually "How do I shuffle an array of items?". The rest of your problem then lies with how you decide to present it, and response to user interaction.

Before we start thinking about your component, your questions are defined somewhere. Let's call this initial pool of questions `data`.

Your component will then accept this data either as props, or it might fetch them from the network. Where ever they come from, it doesn't really matter.

With this data, we can say "OK our initial state for presentation is a random ordering of this data, aka 'shuffled'".

```
  // given our question pool `data`
  // we can simply set the initial state to a shuffled version
  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState<Question[]>(
    shuffle([...data])
  );
```

OK, so we have our 'random' (shuffled) questions. We don't need to worry about this at all anymore.

If I've missed the fact you want it to continue to shuffle the questions as each gets answered, happy to expand on my answer further.

Now all we need to do is display them how ever we like. If we're only showing one question at a time, we need to keep track of that.

```
  // keep track of which question we're displaying right now
  const [qIndex, setQIndex] = React.useState<number>(0);
```

When a user selects or gives an answer to the question, we can simply replace that question with our answered question. This is how React state likes to work; don't mutate what you already have, just throw everything at it all over again.

```
  const handleAnswerChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // create our updated question
    // now with an answer
    const theQuestion = questions[qIndex];
    const answeredQuestion = {
      ...theQuestion,
      answer: event.target.value
    };
    // copy our questions, and flip the old question for the new one
    const newQuestions = [...questions];
    newQuestions.splice(qIndex, 1, answeredQuestion);
    setQuestions(newQuestions);
  };
```

The rest just rests on letting users navigate through your array of questions. Here's the full component:

```
interface QuizProps {
  data: Question[];
}

export const Quiz = (props: QuizProps) => {
  // keep track of which question we're displaying right now
  const [qIndex, setQIndex] = React.useState<number>(0);

  // given our question pool `data`
  // we can simply set the initial state to a shuffled version
  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState<Question[]>(
    shuffle([...props.data])
  );

  // create our updated question
  // now with an answer
  const handleAnswerChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const theQuestion = questions[qIndex];
    const answeredQuestion = {
      ...theQuestion,
      answer: event.target.value
    };
    // copy our questions, and flip the old question for the new one
    // using slice (there are many ways to do this)
    const newQuestions = [...questions];
    newQuestions.splice(qIndex, 1, answeredQuestion);
    setQuestions(newQuestions);
  };

  const handleBackClick = () => setQIndex((i) => (i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0));
  const handleNextClick = () =>
    setQIndex((i) => (i < questions.length - 1 ? i + 1 : i));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Quiz</h1>
      <div>
        <h2>{questions[qIndex].title}</h2>
        <h3>
          Question {qIndex + 1} of {questions.length}
        </h3>
        <p>{questions[qIndex].description}</p>
        <ul>
          {questions[qIndex].options.map((answer, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <input
                id={answer.id}
                type="radio"
                name={questions[qIndex].id}
                checked={answer.id === questions[qIndex]?.answer}
                value={answer.id}
                onChange={handleAnswerChange}
              />
              <label htmlFor={answer.id}>{answer.value}</label>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleBackClick}>Previous</button>
      <button onClick={handleNextClick} disabled={!questions[qIndex].answer}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the TypeScript, but personally it's much easier to understand what's going on that raw JS.

Comment: i dont understand typescript nor have i learned it. i appreciate the time u took to respond with this but tbh it doesnt help much and seems somewhat different than what im asking. for example when i run your code it is not changing the order of questions each time. vyt the questions[qindex].id might be able to help. thanks for the effort there! ill look over this again and see if i ca understand it better a second time around

Comment: When is the order of the questions supposed to change?

Comment: Here is the same sandbox with static questions and no TS :) https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-franklin-1l0kj?file=/src/index.js

Comment: wow @lynden Noye THANK YOU SO MUCH. im not going to just copy and paste this into my app im going to really study your struture and how you did all this. amazing work and really will be very valuable to me for learning. cannot thank you enough. i wanted to ask flat out btw how long have you been programming? i get very discouraged but have only been at it 7-8 months. is it normal to feel lost with this kind of stuff? this is really the first time ive felt comfortable building my own project fully. I have done many api rendering projects etc. but this one has proven to be quite challenging!

Comment: i will get back to you asap about this and see if i have any further questions. thanks again!

Comment: wow... im already seeing how you have your data in a separate file (utils) that is then imported as a prop which can be accessed with props.data..... this is a way to separate the logic like you were talking about. i understand what you mean now about my order being wrong. component => create data => render

Comment: You're most welcome my dude, that's really good to hear. I feared I'd overstepped by going in on a big refactor instead of answering your question directly.

I've only been doing frontend development professionally for ~3 years, but I have a background in design and CSS of much longer. I could read JS before then but couldn't write it well. I've only been digging deep into TypeScript (highly recommend) since starting as a full time frontend dev.

8 months is not much time at all, of course it's totally normal to feel lost. Keep at it, you'll find the groove sooner than later!

Comment: thanks so much man. i had a question and posted it but then figured it out as i typed haha. i am understanding almost all of this will get back to you very soon. and great to hear those encouraging words. i felt a little down seeing that you came up with all this logic for me on Stack Overflow so selflessly haha. also made me feel bad about my skill level but that puts things into perspective as well as inspires me to keep at it. thank you man. cannot thank u enough (and also thank you for answering my routing question on a sepArate thread LOL)

Comment: duuuude i see what the MAIN problem was this WHOLE TIME thanks to you. in the utils/data file i should be shuffling the data PRIOR to passing it in as a piece of state. NOWWW i finally see what u meant about the order... your JS notes didn't have that part of the logic lol but luckily i finally read through your notes again and understood what you meant. this changes eveything. receive data => component => render.... in this case we needed to recieve the already shuffled questions. that way when the component is re rendered it doesn't reshuffle each time! cannot thank you enough this taught me

Comment: thanks so much for this! coming back to this years later and now using useReducer and useContext. Same principles apply! haha. thanks for this

Comment: man how time flies

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your previous random numbers are wiped each render cycle. You can "persist" them outside the react lifecycle.

Create a function that generates a random value and maintains its own cache of last random number generated.

```
const randomNumberGenerator = () => {
  let previous;

  return max => {
    let randomNumber;
    do {
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    } while(randomNumber === previous);
    previous = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber;
  }
};
```

Then in your react component when you need to grab a random, non-consecutive value:

```
const getRandomNumber = randomNumberGenerator();

...

getRandomNumber(8)
getRandomNumber(10)
// etc..
```

[image: Edit react-rendering-and-state]

If you know your max will never change, i.e. it will ***always*** be 8, then you can move `max` to the outer factory function.

```
const randomNumberGenerator = max => {
  let previous;

  return () => {
    let randomNumber;
    do {
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    } while(randomNumber === previous);
    previous = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber;
  }
};
```

Then the usage in code is simplified a little.

```
const getRandomNumber = randomNumberGenerator(8);

...

getRandomNumber()
```

If you still need to handle a range of random numbers then add a `min` value to the function and compute the random value in range.

```
const randomNumberGenerator = () => {
  let previous;

  return (min, max) => {
    let randomNumber;
    do {
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    } while (randomNumber === previous);
    previous = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber;
  };
};
```

Comment: thanks @drew reese but the reason i need it stored in a state is because i later want to render a random question associated with the random state number... i want to set the random state then set a random question to that state to do something like this: <Link to='/question/:id' but have the corresponding id be the random state... if that makes sense?

Comment: @RobertO'Toole There is nothing stopping you from storing the current random value in state for other parts of the ui to use as the issue is with how you cache previously used numbers, this needs to persist through render cycles.

Comment: so are you saying i should pass the state in to another component? even then when the new random question renders wouldn't it technically lead to the same issue? i somewhat follow what you are saying... but still somewhat lost sorry!

Comment: If you're are find local state management in react silly, you will find a global state managemen overcomplicated. But there are is no other way, you should follow or try another frameworks.

Comment: hey guys so i finally moved past the beginning react stuff over the past two weeks since last posting this... REALLY appreciate the help. i basically finished my test application and would not have been able to do it without you guys. wanted to ask since i am now learning A BIT about redux basics if in this particular case using global state management would be ideal. passing all the props down from the highest top level components got realllly messy. and i noticed @levgen mentioned it above... want to thank Drew Reese in particular for his extensive help btw. let me know what u guys think!

Comment: the feedback you guys gave already showed me so much aboit strucutring a react file better... but i also found state management very tedious. if i moved my state to global management with redux would i still be using hooks like useState etc? plz let me know as much as u wanna spill! cheers

Comment: @RobertO'Toole IMO it basically comes down to scope. Generally if more than 1 component can *possibly* care about a chunk of "state", then global app state is probably where it should reside, or in other words, only if you are absolutely sure only a single component needs it should it be in local component state. The redux pattern can be a little intimidating but IMO its learning curve isn't as steep as react's. If it is still a little too boiler-platey for your introductory tastes, or you need a lighter tool, then I would look into the React Context API as an into to global app state.

Comment: yeah tbh im already getting the hang of it after 3-4 days. there is def a lot of routing and set up boiler plate and the connect function gets me confused sometimes but even in a simple app like my test i had to pass all the questions/answers and the score down from the App component to basically every child after. boy did that get tedious. i can see myself getting comfortable with redux fairly quick but i wanted to ask because it seems like there are a few approaches to state management. are the main ways hooks, redux, and context API? . can we use hooks with redux? thanks for the responses.

Comment: my application ended up being about 2000  lines of code. even then i found a desire for some kind of broader state management... i think i can tolerate the boilerplate albeit its rather annoying at times lol.... i didn't think a project of this size would need different state management and am a bit surprised. i was looking for a redux type of state management before really knowing what redux did! the approach u showed me a few weeks ago helped so much though without using redux (but still tedious). is it common to mix hooks with global state in a project? sOME pieces of data using hooks etc

Comment: @RobertO'Toole Well, react hooks, Context API, and redux are all three rather different technologies. Redux is built on top of the Context API, but it is more about the reducer pattern, i.e. pure functions that consume the current state object and an action to act upon the state, and returns the next state. It's a very straight forward synchronous way to update state. React hooks are more about component lifecycle. And the Context API is a tool to help resolve the issue of Prop Drilling, so you don't have to explicitly pass data via props *at every level* to the component that cares about it.

Comment: @RobertO'Toole Take a look at [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) it was developed as a way to try and cut a lot of the boilerpate of react-redux, and it is from the same team, so it should work well out of the box.

Comment: great. i just learned about prop drilling right before i read this! i see what you are saying now. i will definitely check out redux-toolkit. to rephrase a bit of my question now i was wondering if some pieces of state (typically larger all encompassing data that is passed to many components through connect from store etc) using redux can be used in a project while also using the typical useState and state hooks management system. in my last test project for example i can see myself using some data with redux and some smaller pieces of data with hooks. is this normal structure for a project?

Comment: or is it typically one or the other that we generally commit to in a project.

Comment: @RobertO'Toole Hopefully this answers your question, but use the best tool for the job/requirements. You can use both. A simple example of using local component state may be holding the current active tab on a specific page. Since no other page/component cares about it it makes sense to limit the scope and store it in component state. It'll "reset" each time *that* page loads. But take the same example but now your business unit decides they want the app to "remember" the active tab for the next time a user visits that page, then you'll need to persist that in app state. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes absolutely thank u for giving practical example

Answer (score 0):

Try this hook to store visited numbers list:

const [numbers, setVisited] = useState([])
.....

add your number to a "visited" array and clone an array on a button click (react hacks/ways to rerender, while references are compared)

setVisited(numbers.slice(0))